# plugin that can resolve a href values for image in webpack

Tags: webpack, href

I want to use lightbox. In every pattern/library it looks like this `<a class="gallery-el" href="big1.png" data-text="lorem ipsum sit dolor"> <img src="mini1.png" alt=""> </a>`
in dev, images linked by `href`  works properly, but in prod, images "not found"